# I want to call Atlassian's getIssue rest service from scheduler method of Jira plugin which also require user credentials to access that API

Tags: java, cookies, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, atlas

I am creating one POC of Jira Plugin using atlas-SDK and while creating I found 2 Jira version 7 and 8. 
If I want to support both Jira version 7 and 8 in my code then I need to replace only one method each time which is getIssue.
So I want to use Rest API of Jira to fetch All issues. And I want to hit this inside Scheduler.

I try one solution which is using cookie:

Below API requires JSESSIONID cookie to authenticate the call and execute the service
Create Jira rest service API URL : http://10.0.8.9:8080/rest/api/2/search?jql=project='REST'

I did Rest call using HttpClient with header: ("cookie","JSESSIONID={VALUE_OF_JSONID}")

We can use this but as we want to call this API from a scheduler, there are chances that the scheduler is running even after the browser is closed. In that case, How will the scheduler get JSESSIONID in the cookie?

Any other way to access this API? please suggest.

Comment: Saving username and password in properties file could be dangerous but you can certainly save the encrypted username and password in plugin DB and pass them while making REST API call as base auth?

Comment: But username and password may change. And we go with static solution then it can't able to run on multiple platforms.

Comment: Aah! I meant store username and password in the DB not by executing insert query. To store username/password for plugins must have a page in admin section where allowed users can go and put username & password and save the form. Imagine a login page with username/password and a save button instead of login button. If you want to change the username/password in future just go to the plugin admin page again and change whichever field has to change.